# symfony2/fos-user-bundle: Bad credentials works if salt is empty in the user class but why?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I followed the install instructions for installing the fosUserBundle. 
All works well.

With the command line I stored a user in the database

Login "demo" password "demo"

Unfortunately i can't login.

I found in the logfiles the database select. but i cant see whats wrong in my adaptation of the instruction.

`[2013-05-31 14:35:31] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS password7, t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.id AS id17, t0.firstname AS firstname18, t0.lastname AS lastname19, t0.mail AS mail20, t0.url AS url21 FROM fos_user t0 WHERE t0.username_canonical = ? LIMIT 1 ["demo"] []`

`[2013-05-31 14:35:31] security.INFO: Authentication request failed: Bad credentials [] []`

`[2013-05-31 14:35:31] security.DEBUG: Redirecting to /login [] []`

**Update:**

It works if the salt is empty. I dont know why. It would be nice if I can use the security feature.

`/**
     * Get salt
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSalt() {
        return '';
    }`

Comment: could you explicitly do a select on that table, and print out all records?

Comment: please post your secuirty config too